# handlebar templates are not populating in sequence in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise, handlebars.js

The UI of the application is a 4x3 grid. Each tile in the grid gets poplulated by a external handlebar template.

The seqence is like this -

1. Create an JSON object of required data. **data =
   {___:"",___:"",___:""...};**
2. Push these objects into an Array called **dataArray = [{},{},{},{}...];**
3. Pass this arrya to a fucntion which renders the template **createGrid(dataArray,callback);**

The sequence in the template Function createGrid()

1. iterate over dataArray using **forEach((val)=>{})**
2. Pass val to AJAX call to render and return the template data using promises

The data gets loaded and template gets rendered but the problem is sometime the seqence of populated tiles is not correct. Tile one appears in the last row or tile 3 gets switch with tile 4 etc.

I expect the data to be populated according to the sequence of the content in the dataArray but it doesn't happen.

Before I used async:false AJAX call for generating the template and it worked. I know that is depricated and doesn't go with the pattern.

**[problem 2]** Another problem is, I am attaching some images and sound in the template and I am using another AJAX call to validate if files exists or not and attach the file path in the object that is being pushed in the dataArray. I don't know how to call that pathValidate function during object creating. If I use sync AJAX call then I can return the value but with sync call, I am lost

Now the code -

```
// file path validation method 
   let validatePath = (folder, index, extension) => { // file path validation method 
    let url = folder + index + extension;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        xhttp.onload = () => {
            if (xhttp.status == 200) resolve(url);
            else {
                if (index != 11) resolve('img/' + "default" + extension);
                else resolve('img/' + "11" + extension);
            }
        };
        xhttp.onerror = () => {
            reject(xhttp.statusText);
        };
        xhttp.send();
    });
}

let getTemplateAjax = (url, cardData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET'
        }).done((data) => {
            let template = Handlebars.compile(data),
                finalContent = template(cardData);
            resolve(finalContent);
        }).fail((err) => {
            console.log(err + "can't find template");
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}



   let createTiles = (target, dataArray, callback) => {
    dataArray.forEach((val, index) => {
        getTemplateAjax('templates/card.hbs', val).then((data) => {
            let tile = $('<div>', {
                id: "tile_" + index,
                class: "tiles-sub-grid-item"
            }).css({
                'grid-column': (index % 4) / (index / 3),
                'grid-row': (index % 3) / (index / 4),
                'border-radius': '3px',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                'box-shadow': '0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
            });
            tile.append(data);
            tile.appendTo(target);
            if (callback) callback(tile);
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('sorry no template');
        });
    });
}
```

Calling these function into rendering the main menu

```
  let contentArray = [],
        imagePromises = [],
        audioPromises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        imagePromises.push(validatePath("img/com/", i, ".svg "));
    }

    Promise.all(imagePromises)
        .then((dataArray) => {
            dataArray.forEach((val, index) => {
                contentArray.push({
                    index: index + 1,
                    title: title[index],
                    description: description[index],
                    image: val,
                    audio: " ",
                    status: "",
                    url: ""
                });
            });

            createTiles("#main-content", contentArray).then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                data.on('click', () => {
                    let tileId = $(data).find('.card-index').text();
                    let tileTitle = $(data).find('.card-title').text();
                    if ((parseInt(tileId) - 1) == 2) {
                        bodyParts();
                    } else if ((parseInt(tileId) - 1) == 11) {
                        alexaCommands();
                    } else { 
                        let message = $(data).find('.card-description').text();
                        responsiveVoice.speak(message);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            // handle errors here
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Comment: `Pass val to AJAX call to render and return the template data using promises` - no you're not. Not really. You're just firing off a bunch of simultaneous ajax requests - there's no `.then` or `.catch` anywhere in your code, so nothing to do with promises ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But do we have to use then or catch? I am using .done() and .fail() and I belive that what promises are AFAIK Please help :). I learned this concept recently so I might not be using correctly.

Comment: You're not returning them (from `validatePath` or `getTemplateAjax`) so really it's a moot point - you're just making several simultaneous requests - there's nothing "promisey" about it

Comment: also .. what is `createTiles`? you have a `createGrid` which is never called, but no `createTiles` function

Comment: Okay, Sorry about the CreateTile and CrateGrid confusion. I fixed it. Also, can you please help to me make those validatePath and getTemplateAjax function return values. I have used callbacks to get the values from these function. Can you please help here? Even if it is not promisy. I am really confused because a lot of video tutorial on youtube says that is promise .then() .done(). but I belive you are correct. Please help.

Comment: `return $.ajax( ... your code goes here ... )`  of course, now you'll need to do something with the returned value - seeing as you're using jQuery's "almost compliant" promises, you'll probably want to use `$.when` if you're dealing with multiple "promises" and want to wait for them to all resolve before continuing ... on the other hand, if you want the requests to be done in series, look into how you chain promsies (hint: `.then` is good for that)

Comment: @JaromandaX can you check? I have done some change according to your feedback. I don't know if I have got the code correctly. Can you help me to re-write the createGrid function? It is still loading the content randomly.

Comment: Ryder, a large part of your first problem disappears when you consider that the ajax call in `getTemplateAjax()` is always the same, therefore `template` is always the same. Only the rendering differs, and rendering is a *synchronous* mutation of the template.

Comment: @Roamer-1888Thanks I didn't know that but I had the gut feeling that was happening so I was considering making those tiles static and just updating the titles,images or other attributes of every tiles. I am not sure if it makes sense to you. Let me know.

Comment: Yes for sure, that would make sense though it's not the only approach that will work.